# Subdomain of website for Github pages project

Tags: subdomain, github-pages, cname

I have a Github project, `github.com/jeti/matrix`, and I set up a "Github pages" site for the project so that it is accessible here `jeti.github.io/matrix/`.

That is all configurable through Github.

Now, I would like to add a subdomain of my personal website so that the website is accessible via the subdomain `matrix.jeti.io` of my website `jeti.io`.

I am just really confused how to do that because the documentation don't seem to show how to redirect a project page to a subdomain. I have tried a few permutations of what I think should be the correct inputs, but because these DNS changes take so long to propagate, it is really hard to test.

Specifically, I would like to know what value to enter into Github as the **Custom domain** (it seems to me that this should simply be the subdomain `matrix.jeti.io`, but I am not sure, so I have left this blank):

[image]

Then I also need to create the subdomain. I bought the domain through OVH, and they provide a few options for adding a DNS entry:

[image]

My understanding is that I need to add 2 apex records. I did that already:

[image]

What is unclear to me is whether I also need to add a CNAME entry. This is what the form looks like when I try to add a CNAME entry:

[image]

So in recap:

1. I did not specify the `Custom Domain` on the Github site.
2. I created the 2 apex records shown above.
3. I did not create a CNAME entry.

Please tell me which of these steps needs to be changed and how to modify it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

After more trial and error, the answer seems to be

1. The Github custom domain should indeed be `matrix.jeti.io`
   [image]
2. I did not need the apex records. In fact, Github emailed me discouraging it. So I deleted the apex records.
3. In OVH, I added a DNS CNAME entry like this:

[image]

The thing that was confusing me is that I thought that the CNAME entry needed to have a link to the original Github pages WITH the project name `jeti.github.io/matrix`. That was wrong. The target is simply `jeti.github.io.` (Note the period on the end).

Comment: So if I have my custom domain ```example.com``` I should add a CNAME to ```username.github.com``` and on github set the custom domain to ```example.com```. Right? I didn't used /docs, but gh-pages branch

Comment: Let's suppose you have 2 repositories you wanna host: `jeti.github.io/matrix` and `jeti.github.io/vector`. How will you configure your CNAME records to map them respectively to `matrix.jeti.io` and `vector.jeti.io` ?

Comment: @RedaDrissi I know it's three years since you wrote this, but it might help future readers so - **You don't configure the CNAME _records_.** This has to be configured on github in the cname file.

Comment: It is not clear to me what tweak you are suggesting. Perhaps it would be good to write a lengthier answer with your suggestion

Comment: I have the same question as @RedaDrissi , I made it work in Route 53 for my github project with just `username.github.io` without the project name as OP suggested, but would like to understand better about how it works for potential different project. So if I have another gh page project `vector`, do I just set CNAME in it as `vector.mydomain.com` and also set just `username.github.io` in DNS without the project name, and it will work?

Comment: @LoganYang Yes, it should work. As far as I know, in your DNS you only set a translation (CNAME) for vector.mydomain.com -> username.github.io. After that, it's Github itself who directs your request to your project site. That's why you also need a CNAME file inside your repo.