# Custom subdomain with project page hosted on Github pages

Tags: dns, subdomain, github-pages, cname

I have already successfully set up a GoDaddy subdomain to point to my personal gh-pages website. This means that my `username.github.io` webpage is pointing to `subdomain.domain.com`.

As a consequence of this, all the project gh-pages on my github account are changed accordingly, e.g. a page on repository `test-project` (which would have been previously hosted at `username.github.io/test-project`) now is hosted at `subdomain.domain.com/test-project`.

I would now like to set up my GoDaddy DNS manager in such a way that my `test-project` gh-page points to a second subdomain, for example `project.domain.com`.

Now, I know there are plenty of similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of them seems to be solving my specific case. My problem is that I don't know what to add to the CNAME record on GoDaddy. I've tried with both `subdomain.domain.com/test-project` and `username.github.io/test-project` , but none of them seems to be working! In particular, if I put `username.github.io/test-project`, it returns the following error:

> Enter either @ or a valid host name such as: "subdomain.domain.tld"

**UPDATE**
I've solved by following this [Subdomain of website for Github pages project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455900/subdomain-of-website-for-github-pages-project) and having my `subdomain` CNAME to point to `username.github.io.` (notice the `.` at the end). I will do it for any other future subdomain.

Now my question becomes: what does the `.` do? What does it mean? It is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trailing dot at the end is as per RFC defined for fully qualified domain name.

So actually every domain ends with a trailing dot internally. You can actually check this for any website just add a trailing dot in the domain name you will still get the same page. eg. 
https://stackoverflow.com./questions/53450113/custom-subdomain-with-project-page-hosted-on-github-pages

So when you make a dns request for `domain.com`, the browsers stub resolver actually makes a DNS query for `domain.com.` to the DNS server.

Hop this helps/

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does that mean that if I used username.github.io (without the dot), it would have worked anyway?

Comment: It depends on the provider where you entering this info. I guess for github pages subdomain you have to use the trailing dot.