# Github user page and project page in different subdomains of the same domain?

Tags: dns, subdomain, github-pages, cname

So what I am trying to get done is:

1. Have `UserName/username.github.io` served at `https://subdomain.domain.com`
2. Have `Username/project` served at `https://project.domain.com`

I have done these things:

1. Put a DNS record in cpanel: `subdomain CNAME username.github.io.`
2. Put a CNAME file `subdomain.domain.com` in UserName/username.github.io repo.
3. Put a CNAME file `project.domain.com` in UserName/project repo.

Now number 1 works: `https://subdomain.domain.com` is reachable and serves the content correctly.

However 2 does not work: DNS check fails:

```
Your site's DNS settings are using a custom subdomain, project.domain.com, that's set up as an A record. 
We recommend you change this to a CNAME record pointing at [YOUR USERNAME].github.io. 
For more information, see Learn more (InvalidARecordError). 
We recommend you change this to a CNAME record pointing to subdomain.domain.com.
```

Now if I follow the suggestion then I get `UserName/project` served at `subdomain.domain.com/project` correctly, but that is not what I want.

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53450113/6583529), of which this one should be a duplicate... but I guess there is something different, or something I am missing.

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to put another DNS CNAME record: `project CNAME username.github.io.`

It should work.

Comment: Not sure how I tried a million things and missed the most obvious one... thx!