# Two level subdomains with Github pages

Tags: github, subdomain, github-pages

I want to have a github pages site that has two subdomains. It would look something like this: [www.example.example.com](http://www.example.example.com). Is it possible to do this? What DNS records would I need? I already was able to set it up with one subdomain, but I can't figure out how to add the www subdomain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subdomain of website for Github pages project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455900/subdomain-of-website-for-github-pages-project)

Comment: It does not. I have already followed all the steps provided there and am at the point where I have example.example.com. I would like to now add a second subdomain so it says www.example.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by setting up subdomain forwarding with my DNS provider. For example, [www.example.example.com](http://www.example.example.com) forwards to the site example.example.com where the github pages site is hosted. This feels like not a real solution, but it seems to work.