# How to create a subdomain names with Github Page and default Gitpage domain name

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a GitHub account called `example` and created a Gitpage called `example.github.io` .

Now I want to have a subdomain name with the `example.github.io` called `sub.example.github.io` that can access to `example.github.io/sub`.

I've searched a lot on the internet but almost every of them are about "how to use subdomain names with gitpage and custom domain", but I want to know how to create the subdomain names with default gitpage domain name like `example.github.io` and not with the custom domain.

I even tried to change the `CNAME` file (depends on some blog on the internet) but it never works.

Notice: this question is not smilar with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455900/subdomain-of-website-for-github-pages-project), this question about how to use subdomain name with Gitpage and **custom domain name**.

Answer (score 2):

github prohibits to use such subdomains:

```
 You cannot use custom domains ending with github.io, github.com, github.net, github.page, or githubusercontent.com.
```

So you can use either example.github.io/sub, or your own custom domain

Comment: Thanks for reply! So how can i do that? just edit the `custom domain name` to `example.github.io/sub` like this?

Comment: you get it by default. just create repository with name "sub"  in 'your-organization', go to Seting->pages, save. and you got 'your-organization.github.io/sub works. https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site